# Creating a graph that compares the age and survival status

Tags: plotting, import

[This is the data](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Sample-Data-Titanic-Survival)

I need help putting this data in a form that compares the age of the passengers and if they survived or not.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Does this produce what you want?

```
robj = ResourceObject["Sample Data: Titanic Survival"];
ds = ResourceData[robj];
res = Normal[Query[GroupBy["SurvivalStatus"], All, "Age"][ds]];
DistributionChart[res, ChartLabels -> Keys[res]]
```

[image]